# Transform Pandas DataFrame of categorical variables to MultiIndex with count and proportion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing several categorical variables. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'grade':['A','B','C','A','B'], 
    'year':['2013','2013','2013','2012','2012']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

I would like to transform this to a MultiIndex DataFrame with the following properties:

- First level index is the variable name (e.g. 'grade')
- Second level index is the levels within the variable (e.g. 'A', 'B', 'C')
- One column contains 'n', a count of the number of times the level appears
- A second column contains 'proportion', the proportion represented by this level.

For example:

[image]

Could anyone suggest a method for creating this MultiIndex DataFrame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way you can do this to use `melt` and `groupby`:

```
df_out = df.melt().groupby(['variable','value']).size().to_frame(name='n')
df_out['proportion'] = df_out['n'].div(df_out.n.sum(level=0),level=0)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                n  proportion
variable value               
grade    A      2         0.4
         B      2         0.4
         C      1         0.2
year     2012   2         0.4
         2013   3         0.6
```

And, if you really want to get crazy and do it in a one-liner:

```
(df.melt().groupby(['variable','value']).size().to_frame(name='n')
  .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(proportion = x[['n']]/x.groupby(level=0).transform('sum'))))
```

Upgraded solution using @Wen pct calculation:

```
(df.melt().groupby(['variable','value']).size().to_frame(name='n')
  .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(proportion = x['n'].div(x.n.sum(level=0),level=0))))
```

Comment: pipe is nice here :-)

Comment: Thanks Scott and @Wen for these excellent solutions. I ended up accepting Wen's answer, just because I found the method a little easier to follow.

Comment: @tomp It is all good.  We just like help others and learning for ourselves.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this ..

```
df1=df.apply(pd.value_counts).stack().swaplevel(0,1).to_frame('n')
df1['pct']=df1['n'].div(df1.n.sum(level=0),level=0)
df1
Out[89]: 
              n  pct
year  2012  2.0  0.4
      2013  3.0  0.6
grade A     2.0  0.4
      B     2.0  0.4
      C     1.0  0.2
```

Comment: Mind, if i add your percent calculation to my solution?  I don't like using groupby transform when sum level works too.

Comment: @ScottBoston go ahead : -) That is not mine , it ours :-)

Comment: @tomp yw~ happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Stey by step method:

```
df1 = df.groupby("grade").count()
df2 = df.groupby("year").count() 

df1.columns = ['n']
df2.columns = ['n']
df1['proportion'] = df1.divide(df1.sum())
df2['proportion'] = df2.divide(df2.sum())

df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['grade', 'year'], names=['variable'])
```

- while using `concat`, one can assign `keys` that would be the outermost-layer index. Also assign name to this new index with `names=`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame can be created by stacking each variable in a loop, but this seems inefficient. e.g.:

```
d_end = []
for c in df.columns:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(df[c].value_counts().rename('n'))
    temp_df['proportion'] = temp_df['n'] / temp_df['n'].sum()
    temp_df['variable'] = c
    temp_df.set_index(['variable',temp_df.index],inplace=True)
    d_end.append(temp_df)

df_end = pd.concat(d_end,axis=0)
```

I'm hoping someone can suggest a better way, avoiding the loop.